# Proving $R^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}=\cfrac{48G^2M^2}{r^6}$

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, curvature

Show that in the case of the Schwarzschild metric: $R^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}=\cfrac{48G^2M^2}{r^6}$

I am currently studying Relativity on my own. But in my book I found that this problem "is left as an exercise for the reader" and I really have no idea how to demonstrate what they are asking of me and I would not like to move on without having solved it.

Direct calculation reveals that $R^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}=\cfrac{12G^2M^2}{r^6}$

Is there something that I am not taking into account?

I really appreciate your time and help.

Comment: how about computing all the components of riemann tensor and then summing them?

Comment: @Umaxo 
I've already done it but all I get is $\cfrac{12G^2M^2}{r^6}$

Comment: @OscarR - Well, you've made a mistake. Check your algebra. If you can't find it yourself, post your entire calculation here so we can help you find it.

Comment: @OscarR - Without actually seeing your calculation (not posted in v1), a somewhat trivial possibility that I can think of is that you are taking the metric to be $ds^2 = - ( 1 - \frac{G M}{r} ) dt^2 + \cdots$ instead of $ds^2 = - ( 1 - \frac{2G M}{r} ) dt^2 + \cdots$.

Comment: @OscarR Maybe another possibility is that you forgot the symmetries of the Riemann tensor, it gives you a times four factor.

Comment: https://youtu.be/7LkEaG48KgI check this.

Comment: That's the [Kretschmann scalar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kretschmann_scalar) which is indeed $48M^2/r^6$ so you must have made a computational error.

Comment: If you are not using any symmetries, the contraction has $4^4=256$ terms. Many are zero though.

Comment: You can double-check your Riemann tensor by verifying that the Ricci tensor vanishes. Before doing that, double-check that it has all the expected symmetries and that the algebraic Bianchi identity holds.